# Variable scope in a higher-order lambda function

Tags: haskell, lambda, scope, anonymous-function

In working through a solution to the 8 Queens problem, a person used the following line of code:

```
sameDiag try qs = any (\(colDist,q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist) $ zip [1..] qs
```

`try` is an an item; `qs` is a list of the same items.

1. Can someone explain how `colDist` and `q` in the lambda function get bound to anything?
2. How did `try` and `q` used in the body of lambda function find their way into the same scope?
3. To the degree this is a Haskell idiom, what problem does this design approach help solve?

Comment: just curious: are you trying to understand someone's homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **`any`** is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that takes 2 arguments:

- the **1st argument** is of type `a -> Bool`, i.e. a function from `a` to `Bool`
- the **2nd argument** is of type `[a]`, i.e. a list of items of type `a`;

i.e. the **1st argument** is a function that takes any element from the list passed as the **2nd argument**, and returns a `Bool` based on that element. (well it can take any values of type `a`, not just the ones in that list, but it's quite obviously certain that `any` won't be invoking it with some arbitrary values of `a` but the ones from the list.)

---

You can then simplify thinking about the original snippet by doing a slight refactoring:

```hs
sameDiag :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
sameDiag try qs = any f xs
  where
    xs = zip [1..] qs
    f = (\(colDist, q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist)
```

which can be transformed into

```hs
sameDiag :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
sameDiag try qs = any f xs
  where
    xs = zip [1..] qs
    f (colDist, q) = abs (try - q) == colDist)
```

which in turn can be transformed into

```hs
sameDiag :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
sameDiag try qs = any f xs
  where
    xs = zip [1..] qs
    f pair = abs (try - q) == colDist) where (colDist, q) = pair
```

*(Note that `sameDiag` could also have a more general type `Integral a => a -> [a] -> Bool` rather than the current monomorphic one)*

— so how does the `pair` in `f pair = ...` get bound to a value? well, simple: it's just a function; whoever calls it must pass along a value for the `pair` argument. — when calling `any` with the first argument set to `f`, it's the invocation of the function `any` who's doing the calling of `f`, with individual elements of the list `xs` passed in as values of the argument `pair`.

and, since the contents of `xs` is a list of pairs, it's OK to pass an individual pair from this list to `f` as `f` expects it to be just that.

---

**EDIT:** a further explanation of `any` to address the asker's comment:

> Is this a fair synthesis? This approach to designing a higher-order function allows the invoking code to change how f behaves AND invoke the higher-order function with a list that requires additional processing prior to being used to invoke f for every element in the list. Encapsulating the list processing (in this case with zip) seems the right thing to do, but is the intent of this additional processing really clear in the original one-liner above?

There's really no additional *processing* done by `any` prior to invoking `f`. There is just very minimalistic bookkeeping in addition to simply iterating through the passed in list `xs`: invoking `f` on the elements during the iteration, and immediately breaking the iteration and returning `True` the first time `f` returns `True` for any list element.

Most of the behavior of `any` is "implicit" though in that it's taken care of by Haskell's lazy evaluation, basic language semantics as well as existing functions, which `any` is composed of (well at least my version of it below, `any'` — I haven't taken a look at the built-in `Prelude` version of `any` yet but I'm sure it's not much different; just probably more heavily optimised).

In fact, `any` is simple it's almost trivial to re-implement it with a one liner on a GHCi prompt:

```hs
Prelude> let any' f xs = or (map f xs)
```

let's see now what GHC computes as its type:

```hs
Prelude> :t any'
any' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

— same as the built-in `any`. So let's give it some trial runs:

```hs
Prelude> any' odd [1, 2, 3]  -- any odd values in the list?
True
Prelude> any' even [1, 3]    -- any even ones?
False
Prelude> let adult = (>=18)
Prelude> any' adult [17, 17, 16, 15, 17, 18]
```

— see how you can sometimes write code that almost looks like English with higher-order functions?

Comment: Nice, clear explanation. By the time i read "well, simple", I would agree because of how you laid out the logic.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a fair synthesis? This approach to designing a higher-order function allows the invoking code to change how f behaves AND invoke the higher-order function with a list that requires additional processing prior to being used to invoke f for every element in the list.  

Encapsulating the list processing (in this case with zip) seems the right thing to do, but is the intent of this additional processing really clear in the original one-liner above?

Comment: What additional processing? `zip` does its processing as always, the result of which is passed to `any`. And `any` doesn't do any additional processing — it just does very simple bookkeeping: the first time `f` returns `True`, it also returns `True` and stops analysing the rest of the list. I will edit the answer and explain the mechanism of `any` in a bit more detail for you.

Comment: Thank you Erik.  You have clarified my misunderstanding.  I realize part of what threw me off the intent of the code was the use of brackets to define the anonymous function (and the first argument to any), with the use of $ for the second argument for any.  sameDiag try qs = any $ \(colDist,q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist  (zip [1..] qs) works, as does sameDiag try qs = any (\\(colDist,q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist)  (zip [1..] qs).  This last version would have been my preferred somehow.

Comment: I'm glad I was of use! If an answer solved your issue or answered your question, you ought to accept it! As to the rest of the comment, I find it very hard to parse text with non-monospaced, or at least quoted code snippets sprinkled in.

Comment: I know what you mean and figured out how to do in the comment.  Here is the code:  `sameDiag try qs = any $ (colDist,q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist (zip [1..] qs) ` works, as does `sameDiag try qs = any (\(colDist,q) -> abs (try - q) == colDist) (zip [1..] qs)`    This last version would have been my preferred to better highlight the two arguments for `any`.  It may be too much hand-holding, but given the flexibility in Haskell, I was caught looking for more in the code than what was there.

Answer (score 0):

`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]` takes two lists and joins them into pairs, dropping any remaining at the end.

`any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` takes a function and a list of `a`s and then returns `True` if any of the values returned true or not.

So `colDist` and `q` are the first and second elements of the pairs in the list made by `zip [1..] qs`, and they are bound when they are applied to the pair by `any`.

`q` is only bound within the body of the lambda function - this is the same as with lambda calculus. Since `try` was bound before in the function definition, it is still available in this inner scope. If you think of lambda calculus, the term `\x.\y.x+y` makes sense, despite the `x` and the `y` being bound at different times.

As for the design approach, this approach is much cleaner than trying to iterate or recurse through the list manually. It seems quite clear in its intentions to me (with respect to the larger codebase it comes from).

Comment: This is great.  The explanation of q was particularly helpful. Thank you!